# I am using SQL Server Managment Studio v18 but can't find database diagrams folder

Tags: sql-server, ssms-17

I am using SQL Server Management Studio v18 but can't find database diagrams folder
[ssms18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYKuj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Database diagrams are **no longer available** as of SQL Server Management Studio v18.0 - see here:

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/10/pour-one-out-for-database-diagrams-and-good-riddance/

Answer (score 0):

Database Diagrams is back in SSMS 18.1, so download an install the new version.

Answer (score 0):

you can get it back when you re-install the SSMS 18.1 that's been released just yesterday.
i.e. 11th June 2019.

Here's the downlink.
[Download SQL Server Management Studio 18.1](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2094583)